How do I tell whether a Ginkgo biloba seedling is male or female?
I have germinated some Ginkgo biloba from seed. How do I differentiate between male and female Ginkgo seedlings? I would like to keep an equal number of male and female seedlings, so I need know which seedlings are male and which are female. Is there a way to know without waiting decades for the plants to mature?

You can tell the sex of a ginkgo only when it flowers (the female flower has a single pistil) or when it fruits. There are also apparently rare cases where a male tree has put out a female branch or two, that then flowers and produces fruit. Surprise!
I've occasionally wondered which dinosaur loved the smell of that fruit...

He's right, both male and female trees are indistinguishable until they bear seeds or pollen catkins - it's a 20-year wait at the soonest.
